# Moving of object using accelerometer in ipad

Tags: jquery, ios, html, cordova

Hi i am building an app in ipad where i have object, when i move the ipad even object should move using acccelerometer functionalities.But when i use the below code its not entering inside the `Mobeobject()` functionality may i know where iam going wrong.

my object is not moving.

```
// Start moving the object

var startMove = $('#startMove');

startMove.live("click",function()
{
    alert("startMoving>>");

    startMoving();

    $(this).hide();

});

// Start watching the acceleration

function startMoving(){

    alert("startMoving");

    var options = { frequency: 500 };

    alert("insidestartMoving");

    watchMove = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(moveObject, onError, options);

    alert("instartMoving");

}

// moveObject

function moveObject(acceleration) {

    alert("moveObject");

    var myObj = $('#obj');

    var wall = $('#obj_wall');

    var objPosition = myObj.position();

    var leftBoundary = 0;

    var topBoundary = 0;

    var rightBoundary = wall.width() - myObj.width() - 10; // 10 represents the 10px for the margin

    var bottomBoundary = wall.height() - myObj.height() - 10; // 10 represents the 10px for the margin

    if( acceleration.x < 0 && objPosition.left <= rightBoundary ) {

        myObj.animate({
            left:'+=10'
        },100);
    } else if( acceleration.x > 0 && objPosition.left > leftBoundary ) {
        myObj.animate({
            left:'-=10'
        },100);
    }
    if( acceleration.y < 0 && objPosition.top > topBoundary ) {
        myObj.animate({
            top:'-=10'
        },100);
    } else if(acceleration.y > 0 && objPosition.top <= bottomBoundary ) {
        myObj.animate({
            top:'+=10'
        },100);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    <body>
  <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="content">
          <div id="obj_wall">
          <div id="obj"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <a href="#" id="startMove" data-role="button">Start Moving</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Start Moving

Comment: can you add the startMove button into the code above?

Comment: @ClintonWard i have edited the code and posted above..u can check it for button method.its enter till watchmove after tat its not entering inside moveobject(acceleration)

Comment: have you tried using the latest cordova? 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analysing and trying out for long time, i figured out the problem was with cordova.We have to use **cordova-1.7.0.js**  and the above code works absolutely fine...

Answer (score 1):

change the animate code to below

```
myObj.animate({ 'left': -10}, "slow");
```